# docker-compose up getting werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found

Tags: apache-superset

did git pull for superset then docker-compose up getting

`werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server`

When accessing localhost:8088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this solved with:

```
cd superset/superset-frontend
npm install cross-env
npm install -f --no-optional --global webpack webpack-cli; 
npm run build
```